# How to split and verify if a string exists while in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongoose, dom-events, ejs

I don't understand where I can tackle this problem. I have to merge the numbers so the green appears only if the yellow don't exists. But I can't display the yellow properly because I can receive multiple numbers in my DB, and they are in a single string.

[image: Forget these zeros before the number, the code below is not using it]

There is a loop made inside scriptlet tags (green ones).

```
      <div class="lista">
        <ul>
          <% for (var i=0; i <=10; i++ ) { %>
                <% var num=i %>
                <li>
                  <span id="<%= num %>" class="btn btn-success btn_reservas">
                    <%= num %>
                  </span>
                </li>
                <% } %>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Instead of the a loop like above, now information is arriving from mongoDB and printing each one inside span, with the id and the text with a string of number.

```
      <div class="lista">
        <ul>
          <% customers.forEach(function (Customer) { %>
            <script>
              var myNumber = "<%= Customer.numbers %>"
              function splitting(number) {
                if (/\,/.test(number)) { number = number.split(','); } return number;
              }
              console.log(splitting(myNumber));
            </script>
            <li>
              <span id="<%= Customer.numbers %>" class="btn btn-warning btn_pagos">
                <%= Customer.numbers %>
              </span>
            </li>
            <% }) %>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The code from script tag inside the forEach loop is my attempt to separate those numbers and log it into console, this is the output:

[image: Showing how I tried to split those string with numbers that come in a single item from a collection]

Comment: Why would you have a function definition inside a loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
Please post PURE html and JS if the question is unrelated to templating or server processing

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the advice, those pages are great. I'm using template engine called EJS so the HTML and JS are included and for this problem I didn't see what help would be to display my server.js code, so we can focus on logic.
I have this function inside loop because this is how I managed to deal with the variable (Customer.numbers) that is coming from my DB and being printed one by one in the desired element, should I try something different?

Comment: As I said, this is not a server issue. The code you have problems with is pure client code so we want to see an example of your view-source including the script. If you have more than one customer, you will see the useless inclusion of the function inside the loop will add `function splitting(number) {
                if (/\,/.test(number)) { number = number.split(','); } return number;
              }` over and over again. That is waste of bandwidth since only the last is used

Comment: I appreciate it but could you explain more detailed about why this function should be outside the loop? 
This is my Customer database, I have a few, and only one item with a string value greater than one number:
https://imgur.com/LkirIqE

I'll try to prepare a sandbox for better understanding, since I have information coming directly from mongoDB I'll try to represent it with a example array.

Comment: You are not even calling the function anywhere useful. It just does a console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter array of the green numbers using customer array  `some()` and checking if the customer number string `includes()` green number

```js
const nums = Array.from({length:11}, (_,i) => `${i}`.padStart(3,'0'));

const customers = [{number:'002'},{number:'6003'}, {number:'1010'}, {number:'8008888'}];

const unique_nums = nums.filter(s => !customers.some(o => o.number.includes(s)));

console.log('Before filter:', JSON.stringify(nums))
console.log('After filter:', JSON.stringify(unique_nums))
```

Comment: You need to loop over them and create a span for each and insert it into the dom